# Maeder's articles about Logic Programming with Mathematica

Tags: packages

I found by chance Maeder's public articles about Logic Programming with Mathematica  at the following links:
[**Logic Programming I: The Interpreter**](https://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v4i1/columns/maeder/53-63_Roman41.mj.pdf) and [**Logic Programming II: Applications**](https://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v4i2/columns/maeder/38-43_maeder42.mj.pdf) .

The first uses the packages **LogicProgramming.m**, **Unify.m**, **Lisp.m**, **DAG.m** .
The second uses also the packages  **FSA.m**, **NIM.m**, **JurassicPark.m** .

The packages are referred to be contained in some "*electronic supplement*" .

Does anybody know if they are available for download (and where, in that case) ?
Better to know before trying to study the articles.
Thanks.

Comment: It does say the packages work on Mathematica 2.2. That was a while ago...

Comment: You could write to the editor of the Mathematica journal and ask. They might have a package, or write Roman Maeder himself, he is quite approachable.

Answer (score 3):

Got the answer at [Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1610477)

> Quoting from WC:
>
> It looks like they are available from the Mathematica Journal web site. I looked up the [issue where the first article came from](https://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v4i1/), and the electronic supplements are available via a [link at the top](https://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v4i1/esupplement/index.html). The second issue is [here](https://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v4i2/).

Comment: Please make the answer self-contained. Do not rely on an external source which may or may not be accessible in the future.

Comment: @Szabolcs you mean you don't trust WC to always be stable and function properly?! I'm shocked that anyone could think that a site that takes ~60s to load any page and which runs on a glitchy highly non-standard API could be less-than-trustworthy.